# Bootstrap btn-group-vertical pull-right showing up below responsive navbar images in Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on redoing the layout of my Rails 4 app with Bootstrap in order to individualize it, but am having some trouble with aligning the buttons that link to the user's profile and login/logout.

I had my alignment working until I started working on mobile responsiveness and made both the logo and the header banner responsive with the `img-responsive` class. Now, the buttons are below the header and brand logo.

This is what it looks like now on the desktop (with a drawing of where I want the `btn-group-vertical pull-right` to go):

[image]

And it looks like this on mobile, overlapping the introductory text:

[image]

This is the portion of `application.html.erb`:

```
    <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54adc070e4b0c8f53bde4cf9/t/5602e062e4b0d28c8246fa6d/1443029092179/?format=750w" class="img-responsive">



</div>
</div>

</div>

  <div class="navigation pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right" role="group" aria-label="...">



    <% if user_signed_in? %>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to "My Events", myevents_path %></button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %></button>
    <% else %>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to "Register", register_path %></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></button>
    <% end %>

  </div>
    </div>
     </div>

      </div>
      </div>
       </div>
  </div>
      <div class="text">
      Register Now. Win free prizes. Get a free fitted helmet and rail pass while supplies last. Ensure your seat at WHEELS conference sessions.
    </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

While I added and modified these styles in `bootstrap.css`:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-brand > img {
  display: block;

}

.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 200px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.navigation {
  padding-right: 25px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  clear: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: right;
}
```

I added a new div to contain the buttons and modify the placement that way, but it didn't seem to do anything.

I've tried modifying the placement of the button group by cutting and pasting into the same div as the header, but it doesn't seem to work. In fact, it tends to add **more** blank space to the page, putting it below the descriptive text that follows the banner (normally, the buttons are on the same level as that text).

Chrome's developer tools are also not being very helpful in this case. This is my output:

```
Inherited from HTML
wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/media="all"
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}

Pseudo ::before element
wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/media="all"
*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/media="all"
*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I suspect that i'm canceling out something somewhere, but am not sure what. I would be grateful if someone could help point me in the right direction.

Comment: What width is being shown in the Chrome console for .navigation? If it is wider than the available space it can't float.

Comment: @Phil for `.navigation`, the Chrome console shows `width: 100%`. since I want it to pull right and be beside the header and logo, that's definitely more than the available space. so changing the `width` to pixels for that class should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options to make this work. It could take some experimentation, so feel free to edit this answer to fit your purposes.

```
  <div class="navigation pull-right">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
         <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54adc070e4b0c8f53bde4cf9/t/5602e062e4b0d28c8246fa6d/1443029092179/?format=750w" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right" role="group" aria-label="...">
        ... menu code goes here ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This approach uses columns to provide responsiveness, while attempting to avoid having to fix the width of image and menu elements. You can adjust the number of columns at various viewport widths with the xs, sm, md, lg classes, to get close to something optimal. The xs has been set to 12 and 12 in order to force an overflow and give you the full width image on narrow screens.

Although there are other options to do this, I've found that working within the Bootstrap grid system generally is most reliable for responsive layouts.

Another point: I'd typically avoid updating the bootstrap css files directly, and consider loading an additional css file after that just overrides the specific bootstrap classes that you need to extend.